# Find missing values within groups of data using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, report

Recently I need to generate a report based on the fact:

TableA has the following 2 columns UserID and DocumentType

I have been provided a list of 'mandatory' document types: Type1, Type2, Type3 and I need to return every UserID that doesn't have all three of these types along with the types they are missing.

For example if TableA contains the following rows

```
12  Type1
12  Type2
12  Type4
13  Type1
13  Type2
13  Type3
14  Type1
15  Type6
15  Type7
15  Type8
```

Then ideally the output would be something like:

```
12 Type3
14 Type2, Type3
15 Type1, Type2, Type3
```

Ideally, the query to generate the results should be able to handle up to tens of millions of records.

We recently implemented a solution to a similar question (which is a bit more complicated than this) with SQL server 2012. It takes 3 and a half minutes to get the full report among multiple tables with around 4 million records in total. We wonder whether there are better ideas which can do this faster.

Please feel free to share your ideas which can solve this problem.

Thank you! :)

Comment: `select * from TableA group by id having count(*) < 3`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Marc. It is possible that a user can have 3 unwanted types. I will update my question to make it more precise. ;)

Comment: you tagged mysql and sql-server but then you mention you did this with sql-server 2012 but so which is it?  are you doing this in mysql or sql-server row to string concatenation is very different!

Comment: Does your table have any indexes?

Comment: What have you try? If you have a working query why dont share with us so we have something to work with? Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Hi Matt, it is actually SQL server, but we also encourage people who are familiar with other DB systems to have a look too since there's always an alternative way of doing the same thing among different systems. Thanks for asking for clarification.

Comment: I understand the encouragement, and the generic sql tag will already do that but for this particular purpose if you want sql-server you shouldn't include mysql because the mysql technique is a single function called GROUP_CONCAT(), oracle is LISTAGG, postgres has something similar but sql-server has none of those so the other RDBMs won't be of much help if you want the list of types as a concatenated string

Comment: Hi @Hogan, the 3-minute-result is produced with no index on the tables at all. If the indexes are in place, it takes around 1 - 2 minutes (but that's generated on another server with similar amount of data). Indexes can for sure improve the performance. I assume a better algorithm can offer better performance compared to others within the same situation regardless of indexes. (I could be wrong on this though)

Comment: Hi @Matt, SQL SERVER has something called FOR XML PATH which could do similar things.

Comment: yes I am aware of that but it is not just a simple function as the other platforms, plus it does have some drawbacks. if you have XML or HTML or something in your columns.  There are also recursive ctes.  Both of these require essentially a cross apply with a scalar function and potentially a select nested in it.

Answer (score 3):

**[DEMO](https://rextester.com/UVOWB34678)**

```
WITH 
base ([DocumentType]) as (
    SELECT 'Type1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Type2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Type3'
),
users as (
    SELECT DISTINCT [userID]
    FROM Table1 t    
),
pairs as ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM users, base
)    
SELECT p.userID, p.[DocumentType], t.[DocumentType]
FROM pairs p 
LEFT JOIN Table1 t
       ON p.[DocumentType] = t.[DocumentType]
      AND p.[userID] = t.[userID]
WHERE t.[DocumentType] IS NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: This Answer Works!

Answer (score 1):

i think you need something like this

```
select x2.*
(select *
from (select distinct UserID from [table])x
cross join  
(select 'type1' DocumentType  union 
select 'type2'  union 
select 'type3' ) y
) x2
left join [table] y2
on y2.UserID = x2.UserID
and y2.DocumentType = x2.DocumentType
where y2.DocumentType is null 
order by x2.UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the FOR XML path concatenation method:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (ID INT, TypeCol CHAR(5));
INSERT INTO TableA (ID,TypeCol) VALUES  (12,'Type1')
,(12,'Type2')
,(12,'Type4')
,(13,'Type1')
,(13,'Type2')
,(13,'Type3')
,(14,'Type1')
,(15,'Type6')
,(15,'Type7')
,(15,'Type8')

;WITH cteRequiredTypes AS (
    SELECT 'type1' as TypeCol
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'type2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'type3'
)

, cteTableAIds AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Id
    FROM
       TableA
)

, cteMissingTypes AS (
    SELECT
       i.ID
       ,r.TypeCol
    FROm
       cteRequiredTypes r
       CROSS JOIN cteTableAIds i
       LEFT JOIN TableA a
       ON r.TypeCol = a.TypeCol
       AND i.ID = a.ID
    WHERE
       a.ID IS NULL
)


SELECT
    DISTINCT a.ID
    ,STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + TypeCol
        FROM
            cteMissingTypes t
        WHERE t.ID = a.ID
        FOR XML PATH(''))

        ,1,1,'')
FROM
    cteMissingTypes a
```

I believe for checking a large dataset a conditional aggregation query will probably be better performance.

Conditional Aggregation

```
SELECT
   ID
   ,CASE WHEN SUM(IIF(TypeCol = 'type1',1,0)) = 0 THEN 'type1' ELSE '' END as Type1
   ,CASE WHEN SUM(IIF(TypeCol = 'type2',1,0)) = 0 THEN 'type2' ELSE '' END as Type2
   ,CASE WHEN SUM(IIF(TypeCol = 'type3',1,0)) = 0 THEN 'type3' ELSE '' END as Type3
   ,STUFF(
      REPLACE (
      REPLACE (
      + ',' + CASE WHEN SUM(IIF(TypeCol = 'type1',1,0)) = 0 THEN 'type1' ELSE '' END
      + ',' + CASE WHEN SUM(IIF(TypeCol = 'type2',1,0)) = 0 THEN 'type2' ELSE '' END
      + ',' + CASE WHEN SUM(IIF(TypeCol = 'type3',1,0)) = 0 THEN 'type3' ELSE '' END
      ,',,,',',,')
      ,',,',',')
      ,1,1,'') as MissingTypeList
FROM
   TableA
GROUP BY
   ID
HAVING 
   SUM(IIF(TypeCol = 'type1',1,0)) = 0
   OR SUM(IIF(TypeCol = 'type2',1,0)) = 0
   OR SUM(IIF(TypeCol = 'type3',1,0)) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID 
FROM your_table

EXCEPT

(
  SELECT UserID 
  FROM your_table
  WHERE DocumentType = ('Type1')

  UNION

  SELECT UserID 
  FROM your_table
  WHERE DocumentType = ('Type2')

  UNION

  SELECT UserID 
  FROM your_table
  WHERE DocumentType = ('Type3')
)
```

Can't be more exact in the rules than this -- so your compiler will look at indexes etc and optimize.

Unless there are parts of the problem you are not telling us.